# Hook re-render whole page on single change in a sub component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I create 2 Text Boxes one with hook and the another one with the old style, now in Hook mode when the user input change the textbox value the whole page rendered, but with old style there only the text-box rendered not the whole page, if you have the complex page with many objects like (Data Table, form, buttons, inputs, etc..) the single change on one of these components forced to re-render everything and it decease performance, for example typing in the text-box take time to effect on page and the delay time is more than user typing speed.

the one workaround solution is using the callbacks and useMem but if the page is complex(lots of objects as described, and all of these objects has many properties the callback and useMem is very very complicated to handle single object property.

[SandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-yonath-wck9h)

Comment: Ideally you should not return a view from hook. You can play with data in the hooks. Probably create HOC instead of using hook to render view.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how `react hooks` should work. what will cause a rerender in react? two things:

1. change in `props`
2. change in `hooks` or say in a better way `hooks state`

in the second case, the `useInput` `state` is changing so that causes a `rerender` and it's absolutely normal behavior. I think using `custom hook` in that way is not a good practice.

I recommend reading this article for more information on react rendering: https://www.codebeast.dev/usestate-vs-useref-re-render-or-not/